# How non owner can execute signed transaction hash in safe?

Tags: gnosis-safe, safe-core-sdk, safe-core

In Safe web wallet, a non owner can execute the transaction once all the owners sign the transaction. Is it possible to do the same with safe sdk? what are the params need to be send in `executeTransaction` function?

`const txResponse = await safeSdk.executeTransaction(safeTransaction);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct and it also applies to the Safe{Core} SDK. The params are the ones you defined, just the `safeTransaction`, but make sure that the object contains all the signatures from the owners required to meet the threshold.